# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 during NextJS JSON parsing from router.query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Data is being passed through the URL path from my main page to my quotes page component, which works fine but I hit an error when I try to refresh the page. I am using NextJS 13.

**Page component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Header from '@/components/Header'

function Quotes() {
  const router = useRouter()

  const { pick, drop } = router.query
  const uriComponent = decodeURIComponent(pick)
  const parsed = JSON.parse(uriComponent)
  console.log(typeof uriComponent, typeof parsed)

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <div>{pick}</div>
        <div>{drop}</div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Quotes
```

The above works fine during the first time, from main page to the page component, but I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` error during the refresh.

**The expected behavior is for it to work the same as when it redirects from main page to quotes page**, I am still getting the same values from `useRouter()` and the query, decoding and parsing should all work accordingly. The reason why I am doing it this way is so that these links are shareable.

Omitting the `JSON.parse` works, I am guessing that because the JSON might not be decoded during time of page refresh which sends `undefined` to `JSON.parse` causing the error. Is there a recommended method for pairing `useRouter` and `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Maybe check that `uriComponent` exists prior to trying to parse it.

Comment: Yeap, it does. In `dev` commenting `const parsed ...` loads the page without errors. I am also able to log it and see the string, problem is with parsing it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NextJS 13 without appDir. You might wanna parse inside useEffect. This ensures the parsing will only occur when everything on that page is ready to go.

```
...
  const parsed = useRef()

  const { pick, drop } = router.query
  const uriComponent = decodeURIComponent(pick)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(uriComponent) parsed.current = JSON.parse(uriComponent)
  },[uriComponent])  

...
```